# Definition of spatial and temporal coherence in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, everyday-life, laser, quantum-optics, coherent-states

It is often said that lasers are spatially and temporally coherent. Is there a simple definition of spatial and temporal coherence in the language of quantum mechanics? More specifically, can these be stated as constraints/measures on a certain degree of freedom of an ensemble of photons?

Comment: You do not need the quantum theory of light to understand spatial and temporal coherence of laser light. To invite people to provide such answers creates an unfortunate misleading understanding about the nature of optical coherence.

Answer (score 5):

To talk about lasers specifically we need to discuss the quantization of the electromagnetic field, i.e. quantum field theory (QFT).  In order to avoid that subject for the moment and to build intuition I will focus on the far simpler case of the quantum harmonic oscillator (QHO).

The most intuitive definition is that a coherent state is a state of minimal uncertainty in both position and momentum. Since the uncertainty principal states that
$$
\Delta x\Delta p \geq \frac{\hbar}{2},
$$
a state which has minimum uncertainty in both must have $\Delta x = \Delta p =\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2}}$.
What this means is that we can think of the probability distribution of a coherent state as being centered on a location $x(t)$ and evolving under the Schrödinger equation as a classical particle would in the potential $V(x)$ used to define the Hamiltonian. In the case of the QHO this looks something like:

[image: Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state#Coherent_states_in_quantum_optics]

Now, this is all well and good for intuition but we should also ask how one obtains such states mathematically.  The answer turns out to be remarkably simple.  Recall that the QHO hamiltonian can be written in terms of *ladder operators*.  That is, if we take the Hamiltonian written in terms of the usual position and momentum operators

\begin{equation}
\hat{H}=\frac{{\hat p}^2}{2m} + \frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 {\hat x}^2 \
\end{equation}

We can define

\begin{align*}
\hat{a} &=\sqrt{m\omega \over 2\hbar} \left(\hat x + {i \over m \omega} \hat p \right) \\
  \hat{a}^\dagger &=\sqrt{m\omega \over 2\hbar} \left(\hat x - {i \over m \omega} \hat p \right)
\end{align*}

which when inverted to obtain $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{p}$ give
\begin{align*}
  \hat x &=  \sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2 m\omega}}(\hat{a}^\dagger + \hat{a}) \\
  \hat p &= i\sqrt{\frac{\hbar m \omega}{2}}(\hat{a}^\dagger - \hat{a}).
\end{align*}

When plugged into the hamiltonian for the QHO we obtain a very simple form
$$
\hat{H} = \hbar\omega\left(\hat{a}^\dagger \hat{a} + \frac{1}{2}\right).
$$

With this form of the hamiltonian one can clearly show what the more complicated description of the QHO energy eigenstates written in terms of Hermite polynomials obscures - they are nice because $\hat{H}|n\rangle = \hbar\omega \left(n + \frac{1}{2}\right)$ and can be thought of as how many units of energy are in the state.  In this description, the eigenstates are labeled by an occupation number $n\geq 0$ as $|n\rangle := \frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}} \left(\hat{a}^\dagger\right)^n \left|0\right\rangle$ with the vacuum state $|0\rangle$ defined as the unique state satisfying the property $\hat{a}|0\rangle = 0$.

Now, a question that is not often asked in an undergraduate QM course is what do the eigenstates of the ladder operators themselves look like?  In other words, what is a state $|\alpha\rangle$ written in the occupation number basis such that $\hat{a}|\alpha\rangle = \alpha|\alpha\rangle$?  Well, it is not too hard to see using the ladder operator commutation relations that
$$
|\alpha \rangle :=e^{\alpha {\hat {a}}^{\dagger }-\alpha ^{*}{\hat {a}}}|0\rangle=e^{-{|\alpha |^{2} \over 2}}\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }{\alpha ^{n} \over {\sqrt {n!}}}|n\rangle ,\ \alpha \in\mathbb{C}
$$

is such a state.  When one examines the probability of finding $n$ units of energy in this states, you get a Poisson distribution over $n$.

So what was the point of this? You can show that a QHO state satisfying $\Delta x = \Delta p =\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2}}$ must be an eigenvector of $\hat{a}$ (see [this wikipedia section](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_state#Quantum_mechanical_definition) for an explanation of why); so we have found the mathematical description of our coherent states! In fact the gif above which I lifted from the coherent state wikipedia page is the case when $|\alpha|=3$.

Finally, what does any of this have to do with lasers?  Well, in a course on QFT you learn that a quantum field can be decomposed into a Fourier expansion of its plane wave modes labeled by their frequency and wavenumber.  The Fourier coefficients of the classical field, upon quantization, become an infinite set of ladder operators $\hat{a}^\dagger_\vec{p}$ and $\hat{a}_\vec{p}$ which add and remove *particles* of momentum $\vec{p}$.  Just as we did for the QHO we can create coherent states out of these ladder operators, and they are now thought of as superpositions over *field configurations* which have minimum uncertainty around a classical field configuration of specific frequency (note momentum and frequency are intrinsically related to one another due to special relativity and QM).  So this is why lasers are called coherent states: they are the closest possible quantum mechanical state of the electromagnetic field which behaves like a classical wave of a single frequency.

As an interesting aside, these coherent states in QFT are the real source of the famous wave-particle duality in quantum theory.  By taking an appropriate quantum superposition of particle-like states we end up with something very close to a classical wave!

Comment: The question is what is temporal and spatial coherence in QM.

Comment: The terms spatial and temporal are of no consequence in the quantum theory which is the description that the question is asking for.  All that matters is that its a coherent state which means it is a quantum state that sort of “behaves classically”.  For a free field theory, “behaves classically” means it more or less has a pure frequency and wavelength which would be the classical requirement for a state to be “spatially and temporally coherent”.  Most classical light sources do not have this property which is why lasers are special.

Comment: I *think*, but am not sure, the question is about the explanation and relationship, if any, between the classical EM concept of spatial and temporal coherence and the QM coherent state.

Comment: Your equation $\Delta x = \Delta p = \sqrt{\hbar/2}$ is dimensionally incorrect and implicitly assumes a normalization by some natural parameter with the dimensions of $M^{1/2} T^{-1/2}$, like $\sqrt{m \omega}$ for a massive particle in a harmonic trap. Even if you can normalize by such a scale, $\Delta x \ \Delta p = \hbar/2$ does not imply that $\Delta x = \Delta p = \sqrt{\hbar/2}$. Could you clarify whether a squeezed state where $\Delta x \neq \Delta p$ but $\Delta x \ \Delta p = \hbar/2$ counts as a coherent state?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by "evolving under the Schrödinger equation as a classical particle would"? Classical particles don't evolve under the Schrödinger equation.

Comment: Oh, I see. You didn't mean that the coherent state is "evolving under the Schrödinger equation as a classical particle would evolve under the Schrödinger equation"; you used the word "would" to include the verb "evolve" but not to include the prepositional phrase "under the Schrödinger equation". Could you clarify exactly what you mean by "as a classical particle [evolves]"? Just that its spread $\Delta x$ doesn't change over time?

Comment: As for your concern about the dimensionality consistency, you are correct that you would need to include a factor of $\sqrt{m\omega}$ in order to make the answer dimensionally consistent and in fact if you do the calculation of the uncertainties using the Hamiltonian I gave in my response you will find these factors.  These however do not make the state a [squeezed coherent state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeezed_coherent_state) as they can be removed by choosing "natural units" for the problem at hand, i.e. $m\omega = 1$.  Good catch!

Comment: Edited to clarify. I meant that the wave packet doesn't spread out in position or momentum space and when you look at its evolution under the Schrodinger equation the center of the wave packet in position (or momentum) space follows the trajectory a classical particle would in the phase space of the SHO. In the example gif given, the wave packet oscillates back and forth with the simple harmonic motion one would expect of a classical particle in a parabolic well. It is in this sense that coherent states are the "closest approximation" we can get in QM to classical physics.

Comment: This is a very poor explanation. Light does not have a mass $m$. So the harmonic oscillator can at bets be an *analogy*. Here the concepts of momentum and position are mixed in with the definitions of ladder operator as well as the arguments of these ladder operators in a very confusing way. The problem is that it is probably taught in this way and students don't realize that there is a difference it concepts that needs to be clarified.

Comment: Just because light does not have a mass does not mean it is unrelated to the harmonic oscillator.  The momentum modes of a free field are quantized in QFT and their operator algebra is that of an infinite set of decoupled QHOs.  It is not an *analogy*, up to normalization, the creation and annihilation operators for a given mode in QFT are *identical* to the ladder operators of the QHO.  As for the ladder operators, I have defined them exactly as they are defined in essentially any standard text on the subject so I am not sure what your confusion is there.

Answer (score 0):

Coherence in quantum optics is usually described in terms of $n$th-order correlation functions describing correlations of expectation values of field observables at $2n$ different locations in space and time, which can be measured by $n$-fold coincidence measurements as explained in [The Quantum Theory of Optical Coherence by R. J. Glauber](https://%20https://journals.aps.org/pr/pdf/10.1103/PhysRev.130.2529). Coherent states at the $n$th order are those capable of showing constructive or destructive interference at that order.

For a more recent review that describes both single photon and multi photon effects see [The spatial behavior of nonclassical light by MI Kolobov](https://web.archive.org/web/20170812015141id_/http://www.phlam.univ-lille1.fr/qopt/files/RMP_1999_1539.pdf).